# Run multiple jmeter tasks on a machine, how to specify a port to stop jmeter test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I executed 3 `jmeter` tasks on an ubuntu server. Now I need to stop one of them (requires report generation). I execute the `stoptest.sh` script in the `bin` directory and find that only the first jmeter task started can be stopped. This is the test task with port `4445`, which can be seen through the jmeter log at startup. The ports of the other 2 tasks are `4446` and `4447`, so how do I specify the port to stop the test? For example, I want to stop the test task with port `4447`, but keep the other 2 tests to continue, what should I do? Of course, I will not use the `kill -9 jmeter-pid` method, because this is a forced exit from the `jmeter` process, and no `test report` will be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can provide the JMeter's shutdown client port as the parameter like:

   ```
   ./stoptest.sh 4446
   ```

   [image]
2. It's better to use [shutdown.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/shutdown.sh) as this script "asks" JMeter to stop its threads while `stoptest.sh` "kills" the threads which may result in tons of errors related to threads abnormal termination. The JMeter engine shutdown port can be specified exactly the same way
3. It is possible to generate the report at any time even during the test execution, if you [set `jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush` property to `true`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) JMeter will save each Sampler execution result into the .jtl file as soon as it's ready

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know that the `stoptest.sh` script can be followed by port parameters. In addition, thank you for reminding `jmeter` to generate report configuration immediately, I will use it